# Why does the x output onclick equal to the list index that was clicked?

Tags: javascript

I ran into this code earlier and I don't understand why the list item's number on the array index is logged to the console when you click on a list item. Shouldn't the console log 4 every time a list item is clicked? Better yet, shouldn't it be impossible to click on any of the list items because items[x] is equal to 4? What am I not understanding here?

html

```
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

javascript

```
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(let x=0; x < items.length; x++){
  items[x].onclick = function(){
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Reverse question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var

Comment: looking for more of an explanation rather than a solution.

Comment: Because that is how let works. Read MDN's explanation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let neither of the links are solutions, they tell you the difference. And your question is opposite of 100's of questions that say "Why is x always 4?" And the solution is, "Use let instead of var"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get all 4 list items and assign them to items. Then you loop through them by index, starting at index 0 and going through 3, assigning them an onClick which is a function that prints to the console whatever the index was (0,1,2, and 3).

Comment: One other question if it is assigning onClick to each item, how is it starting with 0? wouldn't it start with 1 since it would have already added 1 to x when going through the loop the first time?

Comment: The update part of the for loop occurs after a loop iteration. So for the first loop it will be 0 because x was initialized as 0.  It updates again after each subsequent iteration.

Answer (score 3):

**Why do you think console log should print 4 every time a list item is clicked?**

[**`let`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) defines its own scope in JavaScript, that's why the current iteration value is retained afterwords (when the element is clicked).

Though you can get your expected output with `var`:

```js
var items = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(var x=0; x < items.length; x++){
  items[x].onclick = function(){
    console.log(x);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>0</li>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, I am not trying to do anything really. I just don't understand why it is the way it is and was seeking more of an explanation rather than a solution. I probably should have made that clearer. I do appreciate your response otherwise.

Comment: @Will, that is because of the individual scope created with `let`:)